What's the mechanic labor book time on a engine and transmission swap on 2003 Honda crv?
2003 Honda crv automatic tranny cable throttle body original motor being swapped with same motor except it's a electric throttle. I also have to transfer ecu parts. What would be the shop time on that project please

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!
